# Cant access an object javascript

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a jsx component in React. I am trying to access an object from my backend server. When I console log the whole Object I am able to get data back, but when I console.log one of the values I get an undefined. Here is my code.

```
import React, { Fragment, useEffect, useMemo } from 'react';
import { useDispatch, useSelector } from 'react-redux';
import Moment from 'react-moment';
import { useTable } from 'react-table';
import { Table } from 'react-bootstrap';
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom';

import { projectsDetails } from '../actions/projectActions';
import { fundingSourcesDetails } from '../actions/fundingSourceActions';

import Loader from './Loader';
import SectionHeader from './SectionHeader';

const ProjectSummary = () => {
  const dispatch = useDispatch();

  const projectDetails = useSelector(state => state.projectDetails);
  const { projects } = projectDetails;

  const fundingSourceDetails = useSelector(state => state.fundingSourceDetails);
  const { fundingSources } = fundingSourceDetails;

  useEffect(() => {
    dispatch(projectsDetails());
    dispatch(fundingSourcesDetails());
  }, [dispatch]);

  const fundSourceName = fundingSources.find(f => f._id);
  console.log(fundSourceName);

  const COLUMN_NAMES = [
    {
      Header: 'Status',
      accessor: 'status'
    },
    {
      Header: 'Name',
      accessor: projects => (
        <div>
          <Link to={`/project/${projects._id}`} style={{ color: '#E3692D' }}>
            {projects.name}
          </Link>{' '}
          <br /> {projects.projectId}-{projects.fundingSource}-
          {projects.typeNumber}{' '}
        </div>
      )
    },
    {
      Header: 'Start Date',
      accessor: projects => (
        <Moment format='MM/DD/YYYY'>{projects.startDate}</Moment>
      )
    },
    {
      Header: 'End Date',
      accessor: projects => {
        return projects.endDate === null ? (
          ''
        ) : (
          <Moment format='MM/DD/YYYY'>{projects.endDate}</Moment>
        );
      }
    },
    {
      Header: 'Type',
      accessor: 'type'
    },
    {
      Header: 'Location',
      accessor: 'state'
    }
  ];

  const columns = useMemo(() => COLUMN_NAMES, []);
  const data = projects;

  const {
    getTableProps,
    getTableBodyProps,
    headerGroups,
    rows,
    prepareRow
  } = useTable({
    columns,
    data
  });

  return (
    <Fragment>
      <Table striped {...getTableProps()}>
        <thead>
          {headerGroups.map(headerGroup => (
            <tr {...headerGroup.getHeaderGroupProps()}>
              {headerGroup.headers.map(column => (
                <th {...column.getHeaderProps()}>{column.render('Header')}</th>
              ))}
            </tr>
          ))}
        </thead>
        {projects.length > 0 ? (
          <tbody {...getTableBodyProps()}>
            {rows.map(row => {
              prepareRow(row);
              return (
                <tr {...row.getRowProps()}>
                  {row.cells.map(cell => {
                    return (
                      <td {...cell.getCellProps()}>{cell.render('Cell')}</td>
                    );
                  })}
                </tr>
              );
            })}
          </tbody>
        ) : (
          <Loader />
        )}
      </Table>
    </Fragment>
  );
};

export default ProjectSummary;
```

Here is the output of the above code

[image: image of console.log]

If I add `.fundingSourceName` to that console.log I get an undefined error. Here is a screenshot of the error.

[image: picture with added console.log]

Comment: Is fundSourceName the object that you're able to see? And the attribute fundingSourceName is missing when you try to get that specific attribute? What is the output when you log fundSourceName? (Also, I would triple check that you've got the casing correct - that's bit me many times)

Comment: @ScottyJamison fundSourceName is the object that I am able to see. I am trying to access a value inside that object titled 'fundingSourceName'. When I add `console.log(fundSorceName.fundingSourceName)` i get an undefined error. I have updated my post above to show what I am seeing. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I added the following line to my code and it has solved the problem.

```
const fundSourceName = fundingSources.find(f => f._id);
  const name = fundSourceName && fundSourceName.fundingSourceName;
  console.log(name);
```